# Contact Form 7 wordpress DUDA

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

```
 <label> Porque te gusta nuestro negocio?
 [select gustar 
 "Es una buena alternativa para emprender" 
 "Quiero ampliar mi negocio actual" 
 "Me gustan las facilidades que ofrecen" 
 "Otros"] </label>
```

Buenas a raiz de este campo en un formulario que tengo con contact form 7, hay alguna manera de el usuario al pulsar "otros" cree un textarea para que el usuario pueda escribir?

---

Ahora tengo esto en el codigo

```
<label> Porque te gusta nuestro negocio?
[select gustar id:result  "Es una buena alternativa para emprender" "Quiero ampliar mi negocio actual" "Me gustan las facilidades que ofrecen" "Otros"] </label>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function textarea(element){
document.getElementById("oculta").style.display = element=="otros"?"block";}                 

</script> 
<label style="display: none;"> [text text-889 id:oculta] </label>
```

---

update:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function gettextarea(){ 
var select = document.getElementById("result");
var selectedValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
if(selectedValue=="Otros"){
    document.getElementById("textarea").style.display="block";
}else{
    document.getElementById("textarea").style.display="none";
}}
</script>

<label onchange="gettextarea()"> Porque te gusta nuestro negocio?
[select gustar id:result  "Es una buena alternativa para emprender" "Quiero ampliar mi negocio actual" "Me gustan las facilidades que ofrecen" "Otros"] </label>

<label id="textarea" style="display: none;"> [text text-889] </label>
```

Comment: Tendrías que añadir un evento (onchange) con js que despliegue el textarea una vez que el select cambie como opción 'otros'

Comment: buenas nose poner comentario, y la duda es que no se como coger el valor del select con id = result

Comment: Para obtener el value del select prueba esto si quieres

    var select = document.getElementById("result");
    var selectedValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

(prueba a cambiar .value por .text si quieres obtener el texto visible en lugar del value del option seleccionado)

Comment: Vale, creo que ya casi lo tengo pero me falla a la hora de ejecutar la función, me dice que no esta definida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con JQuery:

```
$(function(){
  $("select[name=reason]").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'Other')
        $('#txtarea').show();
    else
        $('#txtarea').hide();
  });
});
```

Mira aquí:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21006714/make-textarea-appear-if-option-selected

Comment: Muchas gracias por el código al final lo conseguí con JS, pero este código se ve mucho más limpio y sencillo. GRACIAS